# Change Default Spacing in Visio Org Chart/Localisation

Tags: layout, microsoft-visio-2007

I have an org chart and I want to change the way the shapes are laid out (reduce spacing so everything fits on my page).  I did it by hand on my original version, but now I have to maintain a translated version (with much longer titles) as well and keep them both updated.

Do I need to go into the shapesheet for each shape?  What's the best way to modify this kind of thing?  Globally, by position type, ???

Any advice would be appreciated.  My web searches were not particularily useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are options available to control both the spacing in  the org chart and the size of the items in it. There are a couple of places to find the UI for these options and the locations have changed between Visio 2007 and Visio 2010. The screensots below indicate where these options are available in each product.

### Visio 2007 Org Chart Options

This lets you control the **size** of the shapes.

[image: Visio2007 Org Chart Menu]
[image: Visio2007 Org Chart Options Dialog]

### Visio 2007 Shape Layout Options

This lets you control the **spacing** of the shapes.

[image: Visio2007 Shape Menu]
[image: Visio2007 Configure Layout Dialog]

### Visio 2007 Org Chart Spacing

This is another way of controlling the *spacing*

[image: Visio2007 Org Chart Menu]
[image: Visio2007 Org Chart Spacing Dialog]

### Visio 2010 Org Chart Options

This lets you control the **size** of the shapes.

[image: Visio2010 Org Chart Tab in Ribbon]
[image]

### Visio 2010 Layout Options

This lets you control the **spacing** of the shapes.

On the **Design** tab in the Ribbon, select **Re-Layout Page** > **More Layout Options**

[image: Design Tab Re-Layout Page menu]
[image]

Comment: Hi, do you know how can I change the template for the imported objects from files in visio for Org Charts?